# "In the article, it says"

Tags: sentence-construction

As a quote introduction, is it grammatically correct to write:

> In the article, it says, "quote."

It sounds very much like

> the dog, it barks.

Your thoughts?

Comment: Native speakers don't use that sort of construction here. Use this instead: the article says, "quote quote quote."

Answer (score 1):

I think it would make sense if you were contrasting the article with something else (with another source: the radio or TV). Imagine the reporter were reading you fake or stale news and you pointed to the article and said

> But here, in the article, it says "*a contrary statement to what you just heard*"! Who to believe?!

If you are not, just use *The article says "..."* instead.